# Is the behavior of declaring loop index in for loop header defined in C++ specification?

Tags: c++, for-loop, declaration, specifications, code-complete

When I was reading Code Complete 2nd Edition, there was a piece of code:

```cpp
for ( int recordCount = 0; recordCount < MAX_RECORDS; recordCount++ ) {
  // looping code that uses recordCount
}
// intervening code
for ( int recordCount = 0; recordCount < MAX_RECORDS; recordCount++ ) {
  // additional looping code that uses a different recordCount
}
```

The author claimed that he found 3 different C++ compilers that has 3 different behaviors on this:

> When I checked this functionality with three different C++ compilers, however, I got three different results:
>
> - The first compiler flagged recordCount in the second for loop for multiple variable declarations and generated an error.
> - The second compiler accepted recordCount in the second for loop but allowed it
>     to be used outside the first for loop.
> - The third compiler allowed both usages of recordCount and did not allow either
>     one to be used outside the for loop in which it was declared.
>
> As is often the case with more esoteric language features, compiler implementations
>   can vary.

This paragraph bothered me so much because I've always believed that the behavior in the third compiler is the only correct behavior, regarding to the C++ specification.

Can anyone help me to find out which section of the C++ specification specifies this behavior?

Comment: The correct behavior is *"allowed both usages of recordCount and did not allow either one to be used outside the for loop in which it was declared"*. Both GCC, Clang, and MSVC do the right thing.

Comment: How old is the book you are reading? Never seen any compiler do anything but your last expected result recently.

Comment: if the book calls for loops an "esotheric language feature" i'd get a different one

Comment: @super According to https://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670, the publish date is 2004.

Comment: [This answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49448101/445976) discuss how some old compilers used to allow what is now non-standard behavior of loop variable lifetime. Note: for the most part "Code Complete 2" is still a decent book.

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate, since the link provided by @Blastfurnace actually answers this question. The first case described here was common with compilers compliant with draft C++ standards in the mid 90s - before the first C++ standard was ratified in 1998 and some of these compilers were still in regular use until the mid-2000s. The third case is required by all ratified C++ standards. The second case describes behaviour of some old (early to mid 90s) C++ compilers but no draft or ratified C++ standard ever required that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Blastfurnace for providing the link.

Comment: Also thanks @Peter. That's pretty much what I needed.

Comment: Incidentally, C++98, the first ratified standard, Section 6.5.3 "The for statement", para 3 is what requires this, with the wording  "If the *for-init-statement*
is a declaration, the scope of the name(s) declared extends to the end of the *for-statement*."   All subsequent standards, AFAIK, have the same wording, but section numbers change.   That para is followed by an illustrative example of the form 
`int i = 42;
int a[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
a[i] = i;
int j = i; // j = 42`